# Entering the same record twice, in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm reviewing some EF code, and I'm wondering why it seems to be working.

The code is simple enough. We have a table that needs a query to determine the proper fields for its primary key. It's possible that between the time the query is run and the insert is committed that some other process has inserted a new record, so the insert fails with a primary key violation. (This would be better handled with an identity field in the primary key, but that's not a refactoring I can do, right now.) To deal with this, the original programmer used a loop:

```
MyRec myRec = new MyRec
{
    //.. set fields
};

bool isDone = false;
int retries = 0;
const int maxRetries = 8;
while (retries < maxRetries && !isDone)
{
    myRecseqno = getSeqno();

    try
    {
        myDbContext.myRecs.Add(myRec);
        myDbContext.SaveChanges();
        isDone = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        retries++;
    }
}
```

One thing I don't like is that it's catching every exception, instead of just a primary key violation. (Another thing I don't like is that there are four identical copies of this function in four different classes). But that's not my question. Assume I'll fix that.

What's bugging me is that myRec is being added to the collection multiple times, and I'd not expect that to work. A DbContext is a Unit of Work, which means that if the record was added to the collection on the first pass, it's still in the collection when it's added again, on the second loop.

Keep in mind, the primary key has changed, so I'd think that the collection would contain two records, after the second loop, the first with the original primary key and the second with the new.

Does EF use object identity to recognize when you're adding the same object to a collection, twice?

Comment: The default collection would be a `HashSet<T>` which ensures only unique objects (***by reference***) to be added in the list. In this case your `myRec` reference is never changed, so there is no violation.

Comment: I'd assumed that they'd be overriding GetHashCode, in the HashSet, to use the primary key fields to determine identity. Apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

You may be advised to do the query and insert in a transaction, which would place a lock and prevent another process inserting. A stored procedure may give the best performance, or look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/01/11/savechanges-false.aspx

Comment: Doing a query and insert in a single transaction is one approach, but that creates persistent locks in the database. The alternative is to assume that there won't be a conflict, then catch and deal with conflicts when they arise (optimistic locking). Which works best depends upon the circumstances, but EF defaults to optimistic locking.